# Recursive Sequence with different conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to deduce a formula for a slightly wierd recursive sequence i've got

$$
f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
f(n - 1 ) + 1,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
2f(n - 1), & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

What kind of sequences are these? How do i get a formula for them such that if i'm given a single value of n, i would be able to calculate the value of the function without calculating its previous values i.e f(n-1) or f(n-2) etc?

Also, do you have any links that i can refer to to help me sharpen my formula deriving skills?

Comment: Also, if someone can please suggest a suitable title for this question,it will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to rewrite it as (sign error corrected)
$$
f(n)=2f(n-2)+1+\frac{1-(-1)^n}2=
\begin{cases}
2 f(n-2)+1&n\text{ even}\\
2 f(n-2)+2&n\text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

---

To solve this/these recurrences, I would divide into two cases:

1. Write $g(k)=f(2k)$ to have $g(k)=2g(k-1)+1$
2. Write $h(k)=f(2k+1)$ to have $h(k)=2h(k-1)+2$

---

Then you can maybe solve the more general form of this, which is
$$
f(n)=a\cdot f(n-1)+b
$$
If we write $c=f(0)$ this makes $f(1)=ac+b$ and
$$
f(2)=a(ac+b)+b=a^2c+ab+b
$$
and we may suspect that the general form of this is
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)&=a^n c+d_n\\
&=a(a^{n-1}c+d_{n-1})+b\\
&=a^nc+ad_{n-1}+b
\end{align}
$$
and we see that $d_n=a d_{n-1}+b$. This also has the form $f(n)=a\cdot f(n-1)+b$, so it must follow the same pattern. Note that $d_1=b$. Thus we have $d_{n+1}=a^n b+d_n$. It follows that
$$
d_n=a^{n-1}b+a_{n-2}b+...+b=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}\cdot b
$$
and thus finally that
$$
f(n)=a^n\cdot f(0)+\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}\cdot b
$$

---

Using this above we get

$$
\begin{align}
f(n)=f(2k)=g(k)&=2^k\cdot g(0)+\frac{2^k-1}{2-1}\cdot 1\\
&=(\sqrt 2)^n\cdot f(0)+(\sqrt 2)^n-1
\end{align}
$$
for $n$ even, and
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)=f(2k+1)=h(k)&=2^k\cdot h(0)+\frac{2^k-1}{2-1}\cdot 2\\
&=(\sqrt 2)^{n-1}\cdot f(1)+\left((\sqrt 2)^{n-1}-1\right)\cdot 2
\end{align}
$$
for $n$ odd.

---

Here are some of the values for $f(0)=c$ and the even case [computed with Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20sqrt%282%29%5E%282k%29*c%2Bsqrt%282%29%5E%282k%29-1%20for%20k%3D0%20to%2010).

Here are some of the values for $f(1)=d$ and the odd case [computed with Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20%5B2k%2B1%2Csqrt%282%29%5E%28%282k%2B1%29-1%29*d%2B%28sqrt%282%29%5E%28%282k%2B1%29-1%29-1%29*2%5D%20for%20k%3D0%20to%2010).

Comment: Thanks! That was awesome! I'm wondering if given a single value of n, how can i calculate the value of the function without calculating f(n-2). I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Esentially what String did was to rewrite the sequence as $$f(2k)=f(2k-1)+1\\f(2k+1)=2f(2k).$$
Now you feed the first recurrence to the second to get $f(2k+1)=2f(2k-1)+2$, and simliarly for the even case, $f(2k)=1+f(2k-1)=1+2+f(2k-2)$. There is an error, as there is a $+2$ for the odd case, and $+3$ for the even, so it should say $2f(n-2)+2+\dots$. :)

Mathematica solves this as $c_1 2^{n/2}+c_2 (-1)^n 2^{n/2}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \left((-1)^n+5\right)}{\sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right)}$.

Comment: @krvolok: Why should it be $+3$ for the even case? When you only shift the index down *only by one* you have $f(2k-1)=2f(2k-2)$ and should not be adding $2$ there.

Comment: @String Oh, yes, my mistake! I'll edit my comment. - Actually it seems I can only edit this one and not that one. Oh well. The solution is in this case $c_1 2^{n/2}+c_2 (-1)^n 2^{n/2}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \left((-1)^n+3\right)}{\sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right)}$